# Why can't iterable objects cant use the next() method directly?

Tags: python-3.x, iterator

Why can't iterable objects cant use the next() method directly?

I have tried the following code:

```py
ite_obj = ["sudosuraz"]
#new_obj = iter(ite_obj)
while True:
    try:
        item = next(`ite_obj`)
        print(item)
    
    except StopIteration:
        print("done!")
        break
```

Output:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/suraz/python-learn/functions.py", line 5, in <module>
        item = next(ite_obj)
    TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator
```

Comment: You need the line that you commented out. An iterable is not necessarily an iterator.

Comment: ok! so basically we can say that every iterable object first need to be converted into iterator!

Comment: Or better, an iterator is *created* from an iterable. This can happen with the `iter` function, or also happens implicitly when you do `for..in`. An iterable exposes an `__iter__` method, which when called, returns an iterator, which implements `__next__`.